# database fail to create

Tags: android, android-sqlite

The following code it does not create database file in /data/data/.The application run successfully in emulator. 
How can I  use that created database file to  upgrade that database using third party applications?

**tapdb.java**

```
package com.android.tap;

// entry has not been cre

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;



public class tapdb {

public static final String KEY_ROWID="_id";
public static final String KEY_CODE="key_code";
public static final String KEY_WORD="word";

public static final String DATABASE_NAME="tapdatabase";
public static final String DATABASE_TABLE="tapData";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;

private DbHelper ourHelper;
private final Context ourContext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);           
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
           {

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE" + DATABASE_TABLE + "(" +KEY_WORD + "TEXT NOT NULL" KEY_CODE + "LONG);");      
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO tapdatabase VALUES('hello',23334);");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO tapdatabase VALUES('how',242);");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
            {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + DATABASE_TABLE );
        onCreate(db);

    }

}   
  public tapdb (Context c) 
  {
    ourContext = c;
  }
public tapdb open()
    {
    ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
    ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close(){
    ourHelper.close();  
}
public long createEntry(String word,String keycode){
     ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
     cv.put(KEY_WORD, word);
     cv.put(KEY_CODE, keycode);
     return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
}

public String getWord(long l) {
String[] columns = new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_WORD, KEY_CODE};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_ROWID + "=" + l, null, null, null,     null);

    if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
            String hotness = c.getString(1);       
            return hotness;
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: is your creating-database code work? I wonder it's not!!

Comment: your create-statement looks like: `CREATE TABLEtapData(......);`, so I wonder that it didnt' work!!

Comment: If your phone or tablet isn't rooted than chances are you wont be able to reach it. since its really in com.foo/data/data and com.foo isn't accessible unless you are a superuser

Answer (score 1):

Android separates applications from each other by running them with different user ids. Data stored under /data/data/<my.package.name> (the database is also stored below this path) is private to the application and normally not accessible by other applications (unless they share the same user id).

Only root has access to all the files.